# Is the Doctrine2 "MEMBER OF" clause valid for a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

The Doctrine2 DQL allows for the following [SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM CmsUser u WHERE :groupId MEMBER OF u.groups');
$query->setParameter('groupId', $group);
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

Is the **MEMBER OF** clause supported by a MySQL database?

Moreover, focusing on the previous example, is $group the id of the entity "Group" or is an instance of the "Group" entity itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MEMBER OF` is a pure ORM clause and has nothing to with the `DBAL` therefor it should work with any vendors.

`MEMBER OF` is supposed to accept an Entity but may accept an `identifier` too.

Answer (score 7):

I checked `SQL` generated with `MEMBER OF` clause:

```
SELECT *fields*
    FROM Page p0_ 
    WHERE 
       EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 
          FROM post_rubric p4_ 
          INNER JOIN Page p3_ 
             ON p4_.rubric_id = p3_.id 
          WHERE p4_.post_id = p0_.id AND p3_.id = ?
       )
```

Thats a way Doctrine translates `MEMBER OF` clause into `SQL`